# How do I modify this string to correct bad formatting?

Tags: c#, regex, substring

Here are two examples of some markup that I am encountering:

```
Incorrect: "<span>Some info<br /></span>"
Correct: "<span>Some info</span><br />"

Incorrect: "<span>Some other kind of info. <br /> More info</span>"
Correct: "<span>Some other kind of info. More info</span><br />"
```

What I'm trying to do is split each break into a line so that I can display a line as a table row. Currently, I go in and replace all `<br />` with `|` so that I can split on `|`. The issue with that is that i leaves me with an unclosed span.

I was thinking in this case, all i should have to do is move the next instance of `</span>` following the `<br />` to before the `<br />`. But in the instance there is more text following the break but before the span, i'd need to move that entire chuck to before the line break.

I'm terrible with regex, so I can't really think of a regex solution off the top of my head. But regular substring operations is fine, I don't have a preference. Any thoughts?

Comment: This seems to be an HTML question first ("What is the corrected markup when I see this input?") and a C# implementation question only after you have the desired output figured out.  Come back after you have figured out the transformation rules for "correcting" these if you need help doing it efficiently using C#.

Comment: Could you provide a sample output?

Comment: Updated. In short, I really need to be able to take in the html markup, find the break, and make sure the previously opened span is closed before the <br />

Comment: I suggest you clarify that the HTML text could consist of more than one line. The <span> tag may appear at line 5, but the </span> may appear at line 15. Also, a break could appear more than 1 time within a sapn. These details makes it more fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need an Html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(orghtml);

var brs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span/br"); //all br's in span's
foreach(var br in brs )
{
    var span = br.ParentNode;
    span.ParentNode.InsertAfter(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<br>"), span);
    br.Remove();
}
var newhtml = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

INPUT:

```
<span>Some info<br /></span>
<span>Some info</span><br />
<span>Some other kind of info. <br /> More info</span>
<span>Some other kind of info. More info</span><br />
```

OUTPUT:

```
<span>Some info</span><br>
<span>Some info</span><br>
<span>Some other kind of info.  More info</span><br>
<span>Some other kind of info. More info</span><br>
```